# Use create-from-project for maven archetype: Include empty directories

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

If I use `create-from-project` to create an archetype from a Maven project, how can I include empty directories? I want to include a directory like `src/main/java` even if it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I found a solution. After run

```
mvn archetype:create-from-project
```

Go to `target/generated-sources/archetype/src/main/resources/META-INF/maven
archetype-metadata.xml`. Then you can add empty directories by defining them in filesets.

```
<fileSet encoding="UTF-8">
  <directory>src/main/java/application/controller</directory>
</fileSet>
```

Even you can use package name. When you generate project from template archetype plugin replace given package name.

```
<fileSet encoding="UTF-8">
  <directory>src/main/java/__packageInPathFormat__/config</directory>
</fileSet>
```

Then go `target/generated-sources/archetype/`and run `mvn clean install`. Now your archetype template generate defined empty directories.